# Prevent file being overwritten

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

Imagine there are 3 or more independent locations where a file can be modified. These locations communicate to each other through email or mail (direct flash drive restoration). Though there is a big room for flow - to make simultaneous editing to the file and screw up things, this client won't change too much. He rather call everyone that he is working on the last update or tell the other guys that he is waiting for third guy's last update. Anyway, at some point after several exchanges, due to one of participants unintentional error THE LAST VERSION of the file eventually gets mixed up. From this point everyone searches for the last version BY LOOKING THE CONTENT of the file.

This client wants to have a central location (he has actually, that is his PC's some location) and let everybody (including himself) copy any new or suspected new file to this location but prevent file's last version being copied. From this location he has to easily copy, send or open the file and work.

So, here is my concept (2 steps):

step 1: I made an ad to the main application where this file is created or edited. This ad prompts the user to give a version number to the file with every invoked save command from the editing application. In fact the file can be re-saved multiple times but not considered modified (file attributes creation, save etc. do not have great meaning here). This said the user can cancel my ad-in but have saved the file, not saving a new file version.

step 2: multiple solutions:

solution A: I'm thinking to have a folder/file watch and prevent the last version of the file being overwritten. As you know, FileSystemWatcher will fire the change/delete etc., events AFTER FACT so, I have to back copy overwritten file after the fact (w/ some tricks).

solution B: have a database to store all version of files and built-in some shell extension to extract/view files from the database. Move all copied/pasted files to the database (my program folder) and restore latest file in working folder after watcher fires change/delete event.

solution 3: find out built-in windows tools (API etc.) to greatly rely on it with some programming.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.